# Make a c# class "like a property..."

Tags: c#, properties, constructor, language-lawyer

Is there a way to do this

```
Bombs();
```

and this

```
Bombs(3);
```

with a Class?

Comment: What would be the purpose? Sorry, I'm a little lost here.

Comment: I would have to say it would be pretty confusing to use a class as a method. It's not like the current method syntax is incredibly obtuse or anything.

Comment: Further, regarding "why not"... well why haven't you designed and built your own language that works this way? Not trying to be rude or facetious,  but "why not" is typically a very open ended and broad question with no good answer. I can *guess* that no one on the C# dev team has even considered this syntax, and even if they did they obviously haven't seen it through to completion. In any case unless someone specifically knows of the consideration, that's an unanswerable question.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I am really trying to wrap my head around this. What would be the benefit of using say Bombs(3). What would it do? Would you have a class that has a single method that gets called passing the the 3 as a parameter?

Comment: What exactly is `Bombs.Explode` supposed to do? Properties either get or set a value. You aren't doing either. Also `Bombs(3);` is easy: just don't make `Bombs` static, then you can create three instances and put them in a list, array or other collection.

Comment: @DavidArno .. "Properties either get or set a value." the raison d'etre of properties (getters/setters) is that you can do some thing, other than get/set the value.

Comment: @JoeBlow, not quite. The reasons properties exist is to assist with encapsulation and/or to allow other things to occur *whilst* getting/setting a value. Using it in the way you propose is definitely orthogonal to the intended purpose of this feature.

Answer (score 7):

your question is very weird, I can't think of Any purpose of doing so, but I can answer this question as weird as the question is!

Assuming you are familiar with C# delegates:

define your class like this:

```
public static class Bomb
{
    public static void Explode()
    {

    }
}
```

for simplicity I will use the .Net Action delegate, if you want to add an integer to the explode function just make a delegate that takes an int

```
Action Bombs = Bomb.Explode;
// Use your delegate here
Bombs();
```

Comment: I like your rather weird thinking around a very weird question!

Comment: @JoeBlow maybe use a base class that all others inherit from?

Comment: well, this is how c# is designed , the only thing I can think of is using extension methods for the Object class, then every object will have explode function in it , but the only problem is, the syntax of c# requires you to write this.Explode() to perform an extension method, so in a sense it's what you want, but having the exact syntax will require editing C# its self! also, I heared they added extension properties in C# 4.0 but not sure about that

Comment: hi @HassanKhallouf - I suggest you delete your answer so i can delete the question. Keep the site tidy!  and save moderators time